# Determine surface from its principal curvatures

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature

Let a surface be given by $z = f(x,y)$. Assume that, for some $a>0$, $f:[-a,a]\times[-a,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ and that $k_i(x,y)$ are the principal curvatures of the surface.

Can we find the surface from the principal curvatures $k_i$?

We can write a parameterization $\sigma(x,y)=(x, y, f(x,y))$, so the question would equivalent to determining $f$ in terms of the principal curvatures $k_i$. I think one could consider normal sections on the surface, for which we can compute the curvature using the formula
\begin{equation}
 \kappa(t)=\frac{f''(t)}{(1+f'(t)^2)^{3/2}},
\end{equation}
since these curves are graphs of $f$, but I'm not sure if the whole argument works fine. And even if it does, we would need to solve non-linear PDEs.

Is there a simpler way of finding the surface?

Comment: This is in general a difficult question. First, note that the system is overdetermined, because there are two equations but only one unknown function. In particular, the given functions $k_1$ and $k_2$ probably must satisfy certain conditions in order to be the principal curvatures of a surface.

Comment: Yes, @Deane,  the Codazzi equations entangle these, their derivatives, and the metric in a principal coordinate parametrization. See Lemma 3.3 on p. 60-61 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: Thanks, @TedShifrin. Then I wonder, is there not a simpler way to express $f$ in terms of the principal curvatures? Even a series would be acceptable.